# boto s3 bucket object filter with prefix and delimiter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a bucket with the following key structure:

```
path/to/file1
path/to/file2
path/of/file3
path/of/file4
```

And I would like to be able to get the list of "folders" inside `path`. The actual use case has many "subfolders", so I need to filter the listing. Ideally, I only want to receive two entries: `to` and `of`.

Using boto3, I was expecting the two following calls being basically equal, i.e. that the listing of both yields the same result:

Using the bucket returned by the S3 resource

```
s3 = boto3.resouce('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucketname')
bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='path/', Delimiter='/').all()
```

and the underlying client

```
s3 = boto3.resouce('s3')
s3.meta.client.list_objects(Bucket='path', Prefix='', Delimiter='/')
```

However, the first returns an emtpy list, while the second returns a JSON with the `CommonPrefixes` key having the two entries.

**Question:** What do I miss?

Comment: You missed nothing. The result with the `CommonPrefixes` is correct and, I believe, is exactly what you requested. A `CommonPrefix` is, effectively, a folder. It is listing the 'folders' in the root of the bucket, together with the objects in the root (of which there is none).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/134#issuecomment-116766812

> The reason that it is not included in the list of objects returned is
>   that the values that you are expecting when you use the delimiter are
>   prefixes (e.g. `Europe/`, `North America`) and prefixes do not map
>   into the object resource interface.